# Accessing Auth'd user data throughout

Tags: laravel

I am looking to access the Auth'd users' data throughout my views. This information needs to come from a DB query so I can join in various other tables to get the data I need.

The view structure I am working with is as follows: (layout->dashboard). "Layout" being the generic html bits, parent. and "dashboard" being the page specific content.

My first attempt at passing data from the controller to the view outlined that I was only able to access the variable from the child view (dashboard) and not (layout) which I did presume beforehand. My question is, what is the best way to pass around user data, from a DB query, to any view I need it in.

In this one scenario, it is using a peice of data to retrieve the users avatar in the nav bar, found in "layout".

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can use `auth()` helper in your views. `auth()->user()` contains your authenticated user data, but it comes from guard, but it acting as your User model. Usage: `{{ auth()->user()->name }}` or `{{ asset(auth()->user()->avatar->path) }}`. `->avatar` is your relation your your user mode for example. If you use same navbar in your login page and dashbord, use `auth()->check()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lavente. Problem is, my `Auth()` helper does not contain the extra information I am looking for, hence why I am wanting to use a DB query for it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extra information'? Maybe you need [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: For example, if my `Auth::user` contained an id, and I wanted to use a DB query to join this with another table to get additional information, I'd like to pass that additional information around aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a quick way to scaffold all of the routes and views you need for authentication using one simple command:

`php artisan make:auth`

to make auth interface. 
[Check Laravel Doc:authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

And then, try below...

Query DB like this...

```
//Controller 
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
return view('layout', compact('users'));
```

After get the users collection, then send to view Blade(in the html file) like this...

```
//`Layout.blade.php` as View file like this..
<div class="container">
  @foreach($users as $user)
    {{$user->name}}
    {{$user->"any you want"}}
  @endforeach
</div>
```

[#displaying-pagination-results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Enjoy coding~!! :)